# Meteor template subscriptions and performance

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm looking for advice on my approach here- I want to be sure I'm doing things in the "meteor way" and keeping the code fast.

**Current situation:**

We have a collection for Questions. Each question has a nested collection of Answers. Through a REST API, a device relays the answers that were selected by users.

Based on the answers that were selected, we show a chart for each question- simple number breakdowns and percentage bars. To improve performance, we've been tracking the number of responses each Answer has received on the Answer itself.

The publication looks (basically) like this:

```
Meteor.publish('questionsBySiteID', function(site_id){
  return Questions.find({site_id: site_id});
});
```

And the route like this:

```
Router.route('/sites/:_id/questions', {
  name: 'questionsList',
  waitOn: function(){
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('questionsBySiteID', this.params._id),
    ];
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      publishedQuestions: Questions.find(
        { site_id   : this.params._id, active: true, deleted: {$ne: true} },
        { sort      : { order: 1} }
      ),
      archivedQuestions :  Questions.find(
        { site_id    : this.params._id, active: false, deleted: {$ne: true} },
        { sort      : { updated_at: -1 } }
      ),
      deletedQuestions  :   Questions.find(
        { site_id    : this.params._id, deleted: true },
        { sort      : { updated_at: -1 } }
      )
    };
  }
});
```

**Change required:**

Now we want responses to be date-filterable. This means the denormalized response counts we've tracked on Answers aren't very useful. We've been tracking another collection (Responses) with more a "raw" version of the data. A Response object tracks the module (`questions` in this case), question_id, answer_id, timestamp, id for the customer the question belongs to, etc.

**Question:**

Is this something that template subscriptions help with? Perhaps we need a publication that accepts a question_id and optional start/end dates for the filter. The stats template for each question would be subscribed to applicable Responses data in `Template.question.create()`. Based on the question_id, the publication would need to find Responses for related answers within the date filter. And maybe we use [the publish-counts package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts) to count the number of times each answer was selected and publish those counts.

The Responses collection will be quite large, so I'm trying to be careful about what I publish here. I don't want to `waitOn` all Responses to be published.